# Help Simplifying Function with Bessel Functions

Tags: complex-numbers, bessel-functions, machine-precision

I'm trying to calculate a function that includes Bessel functions and am running into precision issues, generally due to a small difference between large numbers.

The function is

$$F=\frac{J_0(K\phi)Y_1(\phi)-J_1(\phi)Y_0(K\phi)}{J_0(\phi)Y_1(\phi)-J_1(\phi)Y_0(\phi)} $$

where $J$ and $Y$ are the first and second Bessel functions. The overall function is on the order of unity, but both numerator and denominator tend to zero for the values I'm interested in.  I've tried various rearrangements (including using a normalized Bessel function) but to no avail. I feel there should be some simplification that can be made to help with precision.

As an example, for k=1.05 and $\phi$= -40 000 + 20i, with double precision I get INF because the denominator is zero, whereas when using quadruple precision I get a reasonable results of -0.5533 + 1.0666i.

Any ideas?

edit:
Thanks Paul Enta for the Wronskian link (denominator  = $-2/(\pi\phi)$).  I think that solves half of the problem.  However, the numerator is still problematic.  If I calculate it as shown above I get 0 (quad precision gives -8.8151e-06 + 1.6972e-05i).  If I rewrite it in terms of ratios:
$$J_0(k\phi)Y_1(\phi)\left[1-\frac{J_1(\phi)}{Y_1(\phi)}\frac{Y_0(k\phi)}{J_0(k\phi)}\right]$$
then I also get poor results as the ratios are close to unity.

Comment: This expression can be simplified as its denominator is the [Wronskian of both Bessel functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.5.E2): $$J_0(\phi)Y_1(\phi)-J_1(\phi)Y_0(\phi)=-\frac2{\pi \phi}$$.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. That's halfway to a solution.  See edit to question above.

Comment: For such large values of $\phi$, plugging the asymptotic expansions of [$J_\nu$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E3) and of [$Y_\nu$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E4) in the numerator is enough. Keeping the first term only $$-\frac2\pi\frac{\cos(\phi(k-1))}{\phi\sqrt k}$$ gives the calculated result.

Comment: The combination of the Wronskian and asymptotic approximation works.  If you want internet points, write it up as an answer and I'll pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating the numerator for small values of $\phi$ and $k\phi$ should not pose numerical problems. For large values, we can use the asymptotic expansions of [$J_\nu$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E3) and [$Y_\nu$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E4). After simplification of the trigonometric expressions and  by keeping two terms, one obtains of the following asymptotic expansion
\begin{equation}
 J_0(K\phi)Y_1(\phi)-J_1(\phi)Y_0(K\phi)\simeq -\frac{2}{\pi\phi\sqrt{K}}\left[\cos\left( \phi(K-1) \right)+(3K+1)\frac{\sin\left( \phi(K-1) \right)}{8\phi K}\right]
\end{equation}
Then, for large arguments, taking into account the simplification of the denominator which is a Wronskian,
\begin{equation}
 F\simeq\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\left[\cos\left( \phi(K-1) \right)+(3K+1)\frac{\sin\left( \phi(K-1) \right)}{8\phi K}\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, I'll be including this simplification in a journal paper. If you'd like to be listed in the acknowledgements as anything other than "Stack Exchange user Paul Enta", let me know.

Comment: I am happy to see that this answer can be useful to you. Thanks for proposing to acknowledge this contribution in your paper. I think that it can be a good advertisment for MSE in your community. I wish you the best for this article and for the next ones!